# How Can I import robot file from different locations

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a path of a project like this.

```
Main project
'-Service
   '-Main service
      '- A.robot
      '- B.robot
'-resource.robot
```

When I run B.robot I would like to call resource.robot in setting file in my code

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   Test building
Resource        resource.robot
Test Template   Send data to bus
```

I expect to include resoucre.robot, but It's return resource.robot does not exist.

How can I import resouce.robot.

Answer (score 2):

```
Resource        resource.robot
```

Would work if resource.robot was at same (directory) level as B.robot...

```
Main project
'-Service
   '-Main service
      '- A.robot
      '- B.robot
      '-resource.robot
```

You could give it the full path.

You could just use ${CURDIR}

```
Resource        ${CURDIR}/../resource.robot
```

You also have https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#built-in-variables

Comment: I can not move this file to the same directory. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No. I was just giving an example of why it wasn't working. My bad :) Like I said above, you can use full path to file when importing or use ${CURDIR} and a relative path.

Comment: It is always advisable to give the relative path and not use the full/absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use a path relative to the test file. For example, in B.robot you would refer to the resource file like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource  ../../resource.robot
```

Robot will also search through the module search path, so you could define PYTHONPATH to include the directory with your resource files.

The user guide says this about [locating resource files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#taking-resource-files-into-use):

> If the path is given in an absolute format, it is used directly. In other cases, the resource file is first searched relatively to the directory where the importing file is located. If the file is not found there, it is then searched from the directories in Python's module search path. The path can contain variables, and it is recommended to use them to make paths system-independent (for example, ${RESOURCES}/login_resources.robot or ${RESOURCE_PATH}). Additionally, forward slashes (/) in the path are automatically changed to backslashes () on Windows.